# External unit normal field of cylinder

Tags: integration

> > Hello, I consider
> >     $$
> > A:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq 1,0\leq z\leq 1\right\}
> > $$
> >     and
> >     $$
> > v(x,y,z):=(x^3,x^2y,zx^2).
> > $$
> >     and the task is to calculate the surface of $A$ by using the integral theorem of Gauß.

I guess it is meant to use
$$
\int\limits_{\partial A}\langle v,w\rangle\, dS=\int\limits_A\mbox{div } v\, d^3x,
$$
where $w$ is the external unit normal field of $\partial A$.

Am I right that the external normal field of $\partial A$ is given by $w(x)=e_3$, when $x$ is in the "cover" of the cylinder $A$, $w(x)=-e_3$, when $x$ is in the "ground" of the cylinder "A" and $w(x)=(x,y,0)$ is $x$ is the rest of the cylinder $A$?

Comment: You're right about the direction, but to be absolutely accurate, when $(x,y,z)$ is in the "cover" of the cylinder, the external normal is $(x,y,z)+e_{3}=(x,y,z+1)$, ad likewise, when $(x,y,z)$ is in the "ground" of the cylinder, the external normal is $(x,y,z)-e_{3}=(x,y,z-1)$. The normal has to begin at the point on the cylinder.

Comment: I don't see your point. Let $(x,y,z)$ be in the cover of the cylinder. Then the external unit normal vector is the connection vector from $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,y,z+1)$ and this is to my knowledge $(0,0,1)=e_3$.

Comment: I think you meant "the task is to calculate **the flux through** the surface of $A$". When I read the boxed text as currently worded it seems like you want to identify the surface, or to compute its surface area (which is why you got the non-helpful answer).

Comment: @NoySoffer Incorrect. The normal at point $p=(x,y,z)$ lives in a vector space whose origin is, loosely speaking, already "located at $p$". (Very technically, the normal vector at $p$ is an element of the [normal space](http://enwp.org/Normal_bundle) $N_p A$ as embedded in the [tangent space](http://enwp.org/Tangent_space) $T_p \mathbb R^3 \cong \mathbb R^3$.) With your definition, normal vectors and tangent vectors will generally not be orthogonal and Gauss's theorem would have to be modified. The OP is correct that the normal for points on the top cover of the cylinder is $e_3$ and so on.

Answer (score -1):

> $\displaystyle{\vec{r}_{\perp} \equiv x\,\hat{x}\ +\ y\,\hat{y}}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\left\vert{\rm d}\vec{S}\right\vert
& = &
\int\hat{r}_{\perp}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{S}
=
\int\nabla\cdot\left(\vec{r}_{\perp} \over r_{\perp}\right)\,{\rm d}V
=
\int\left\lbrack
\vec{r}_{\perp}\cdot\nabla\left(1 \over r_{\perp}\right)
+
{1 \over r_{\perp}}\,\nabla\cdot\vec{r}_{\perp}
\right\rbrack\,{\rm d}V
\\
& = &
\int\left\lbrack
\vec{r}_{\perp}\cdot\left({-1 \over r_{\perp}^{2}}\,{\vec{r}_{\perp} \over r_{\perp}}\right)
+
{1 \over r_{\perp}}\,2
\right\rbrack\,{\rm d}V
=
\int{1 \over r_{\perp}}\,{\rm d}V
=
\int_{0}^{r}{\rm d}r_{\perp}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,{\rm d}\theta\int_{0}^{h}{\rm d}z
\\
& = &
2\pi rh
\end{eqnarray*}